# Is it possible to create a loop that would create several excel files?

Tags: loops, xlsxwriter

I would like to have a loop that would create several excel files.

Here an idea of what I am trying to do. Of course the 'a' here is not a variable. I don't know how to get the 'a' as a variable.

```
import xlsxwriter

for a in range(7):

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('a.xlsx') 
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("My sheet") 
    workbook.close()
```

Any idea about my problem ? Thanks

Comment: What language is this VB.net, VBA, Python? Best practice is to add a tag for the language. A quick google on xlsxwriter sends me here to a Python extension: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using python, but now I git the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way, just use 'a' (which is varying from 0 to 7, so it's a variable) in your file name to don't erase the previous one:

```
import xlsxwriter

for a in range(7):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(str(a) + '.xlsx') 
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("My sheet") 
    workbook.close()
```

You could use an array containing all file names if you need specific names.

```
import xlsxwriter

file_names = [ "toto", "titi", "tata" ]

for file_name in file_names:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_name + '.xlsx') 
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("My sheet") 
    workbook.close()
```